# Concat mpeg-ts files to mp4 missing keyframe data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, keyframe, ffprobe

I have written custom code to [concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol) multiple mpeg-ts files into an mp4 video file. I've used as reference the [remuxing](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c) code sample.

I'm having issues where the final output is unable to fast-forward or rewind as the video loses its information and plays the same frame till the end. But if I play from the beginning it plays fine.

I compared using ffprobe and a hex tool my custom code remuxer results to that of using the following terminal command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.ts|input2.ts|input3.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

To my surprise, the videos look almost identical but I'm noticing that I'm missing **stss** values on the MP4 header. This is where the key and intra frames are stored according to the [MP4 Specs](https://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt). I'm wondering if I'm missing something on my code. Please find below how I'm currently doing things.

```
int remuxVideos() {
    // Other code removed....
    //

    for (auto file : files) {
    if (FcStringUtils::endsWith(file.c_str(), ".ts") &&
        FC_TIMELAPSE_ACTIVE_RECORDING_FILENAME != file) {
        FcVideoStream videoStream;
        
        error = videoStream.openStream(sourceDir + "/" + file);
        if (ERROR_NO_ERROR != error) {
            break;
        }
        
        // If the format context is not yet open, we open it using the stream
        // settings.
        if (!mpFormatCtx) {
            error = openFormatContext(sourceDir + "/app.mp4", videoStream.getStream());
            if (ERROR_NO_ERROR != error) {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // Read video stream frames and mux them back into output.
        int64_t pts = 0;
        int64_t dts = 0;
        int64_t duration = 0;
        int ret = 0;
        
        while (1) {
            ret = videoStream.readFrame(pPacket);
            if (0 > ret) {
                // Any error we are technically EOF or just an error.
                break;
            }
            
            if (pPacket->duration == AV_NOPTS_VALUE || pPacket->dts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE || pPacket->pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                LOGE("Invalid packet time");
                continue;
            }
            
            pPacket->stream_index = 0;
            pPacket->pos = -1;
            // pPacket->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY; // << Does not make a difference
            
            // pts and dts should increase monotonically pts should be >= dts
            pts = pPacket->pts;
            pPacket->pts += nextPts;
            dts = pPacket->dts;
            pPacket->dts += nextDts;
            duration = pPacket->duration;
            
            // Write packet to encoder.
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(mpFormatCtx, pPacket);
            if (0 > ret) {
                LOGE("Failed to write frame! ret=%d %s", ret, av_err2str(ret));
                break;
            }
            
            // Release packet regardless if write frame failed.
            av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        }
        
        // Update last dts and pts.
        nextDts = nextDts + dts + duration;
        nextPts = nextPts + pts + duration;
        
        videoStream.closeStream();
    }
}

if (ERROR_NO_ERROR == error) {
    av_write_trailer(mpFormatCtx);
    
    // close output
    avio_closep(&mpFormatCtx->pb);
}

av_packet_free(&pPacket);
if (mpFormatCtx) {
    mpVideoStream = nullptr;
    avformat_free_context(mpFormatCtx);
}

int openFormatContext(const std::string &output, AVStream *pSourceStream) {
    int ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&mpFormatCtx,
                                         nullptr,
                                         nullptr,
                                         output.c_str());
    if (!mpFormatCtx) {
        LOGE("Unable to output codec: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }
    
    mpFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = ffmpeg_interrupt_cb;
    mpFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque = this;
    
    /*
     * since all input files are supposed to be identical (framerate, dimension, color format, ...)
     * we can safely set output codec values from first input file
     */
    mpVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(mpFormatCtx, nullptr);
    
    ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(mpVideoStream->codecpar, pSourceStream->codecpar);
    if (0 > ret) {
        LOGE("Failed to copy codec parameters");
        return ret;
    }
    
    mpVideoStream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    
    av_dump_format(mpFormatCtx, 0, output.c_str(), 1);
    
    ret = avio_open(&mpFormatCtx->pb, output.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (0 > ret) {
        LOGE("Error occurred when opening output file: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }
    
    ret = avformat_write_header(mpFormatCtx, nullptr);
    if (0 > ret) {
        LOGE("Error occurred when opening output file: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, by scrubbing you mean actually fast forwarding and rewinding and seeing the full content move forwards and back at speed, not simply hovering over the timeline and seeing the small preview frames, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Also if I fast-forward to a point in the video and press play nothing shows unless I play from the beginning.

Comment: @Jona You are using "concat protocol" that places file parts one after the other (in binary level). Try using "concat demuxer" instead.

Comment: Hey @Rotem, so I'm using "concat protocol" on the terminal and it works perfect. I'm sure "concat demuxer" works well too. My problem is doing the concat by code. Doing the actual dirty work. There is a flag or something I'm missing on the MP4 headers...

Comment: I see... are you asking about the [remuxing](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c) code sample, or asking about your custom code that you are not showing us? Does forwarding and rewinding work when remuxing a single TS file to MP4 (without concatenation)?

Comment: @Rotem I just checked and it still doesn't work. I know I shared no code. I could add something. I just realized that the "stss" value on the MP4 header is missing when using my custom code remuxer. That's all it's missing! Now I need to figure out why? Accourding to the MP4 specs stss contains key/intra frame. Somehow I'm not including that information when muxing.

Answer (score 1):

Well after about a day or so investigating I found the solution. Every new file that I start muxing into the mp4 I need to make sure to mark the first AVPacket as a keyframe. Here's how you do that.

```
// Make the first packet of the ts file a keyframe.
if (pPacket->pts == 0) {
    pPacket->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
}
```